# How to update libssl file on Mac 10.8

Tags: php, macos, installation, osx-mountain-lion, libssl

I try to install apache+php+mysql environment on my Mac(with Mountain Lion), but the php does not work. Seems like the problem is about the libssl file.

When I try the command

`php -v`

The system returns

`dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../lib/libssl.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libpq.5.dylib requires version 1.0.0 or later, but libssl.0.9.8.dylib provides version 0.9.8
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

The details info about the file is as bellow

`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   402K Jul 25  2012 libssl.0.9.7.dylib

-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   606K Sep 13 18:04 libssl.0.9.8.dylib

lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    18B Jul 25  2012 libssl.dylib -> libssl.0.9.8.dylib`

So how can I update the version of libssl file?